# Function returning a class with a generic type, to returning a class with a specific type

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, factory

If I have the following function:

```
        public IGenericInterface<T> GetSomething<T>(T GenericType)
        {
            switch (GenericType)
            {
                case SpecificType spec:
                    return new DerivedClass();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
```

`DerivedClass` is derived from `IGenericInterface<SpecificType>`. However I'm getting `Cannot implicitly convert type DerivedClass to IGenericInterface<T>`.

Why is this happening and is it something that is possible to do? How can I implement a function like this to return any specific implementation of `IGenericInterface<T>`

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). `IGenericInterface<Base>` has no relation to `IGenericInterface<Derived>`. They are completely different types even if `Derived` "is-a" `Base`

Comment: @Fildor that answers it. Thanks.